# How to concatenate string with multi-line string from file in Power Shell?

Tags: powershell

So I have a string I'm trying to prefix onto a multi-line string I'm getting from a file via `cat`. When I'm not trying to concatenate the strings, I'm getting the multi-line output just fine like this:

```
>echo @(cat "..\..\Desktop\Lorem Ipsum.txt")
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

But when I try to do concatenation to prefix the string `"caption:"` then the output becomes single-line like this:

```
> echo @("caption:" + @(cat "..\..\Desktop\Lorem Ipsum.txt"))
caption:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

I thought maybe it was because the first `@(...)` was crunching the output of the nested `@(...)` but double-wrapping it seems to respect the newlines:

```
> echo @(@(cat "..\..\Desktop\Lorem Ipsum.txt"))
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

How do I apply the prefix without `echo` turning the final string into a single line?

For context, I'm using Windows 11 Pro 22H2.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to concatenate an array of strings outputted by `cat` (alias for [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.3)) with a single string (`"caption:"`). When you attempt such operation in PowerShell, the array on the right side of the operation will be first coerced to a string and when arrays are coerced to strings they get joined by [`$OFS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.3#ofs) (a space by default).

Example:

```
'' + @(
    'foo'
    'bar'
    'baz'
) # => Results in: foo bar baz
```

What you can do instead is use the [`-Raw` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.3#-raw) from `Get-Content` so that the file content is outputted as a single *multi-line string* then no coercion is attempted:

```bash
"caption:" + (Get-Content "..\..\Desktop\Lorem Ipsum.txt" -Raw)
```

Worth noting, `echo` ([`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7.3)) and the [array subexpression operator `@( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--) are both unnecessary.

Comment: I do not find `OFS` on PowerShell Core 7.3.7 on Windows or wsl. `$null -eq $Env:OFS` `$null -eq $Variable:OFS` I see that an array is concatenated with a SPACE character, `'x' + @('now','is','the','time')`, but no `OFS` variable.

Comment: @lit it is there, its not an `env:` var tho, it's a preference var: `$OFS = 'hi'; [string](0..10)`

Comment: Which PSProvider hosts the OFS variable? There is not a '`Preference` provider. It is not in `Env:` or `Variable:`.

Comment: @lit the description given in the link I added explicitly says, "By default, the `$OFS` variable doesn't exist and the output file separator is a space,...". If the engine doesnt see that variable having assigned a specific value it will use a space by default.

Comment: I see the doc now. This does not seem to be the best way to operate. Do you know of any technical reason Microsoft would not have made `$OFS` a real variable?

Comment: @lit: Probably an oversight. Looks like only `$OFS`, `$Transcript` and the `$Log*` preference variables are _not_ predefined. Predefining them is preferable, as that makes accidental use of variables with these names for custom purposes less likely. On a related note: The sheer number of PowerShell's preference and automatic variables is problematic with respect to potential name collisions, and they can't be discovered programmatically. Putting them in a _separate namespace_ [was discussed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4216#issuecomment-315493182), but never went anywhere.